# Is there a logical difference between nested Min (), Max () functions in PHP?

Tags: php, logic

Is there a logical difference between these two functions ?

```php
min ( $a , $b , $c ) ;
```

and

```php
min ( $a , min ( $b , $c ) ) ;
```

**Edit**

Currently developing a tiny class to manage a **colour** object for manipulating channel values between colour spaces like ; *RGBtoHEX*, *RGBtoCMYK* etc ... While I was looking for some sample code to make better understanding about conversion algorithms, many of functions written have the second method implemented to calculate min, max values of given RGB channel like ;

```php
$min = min ( $R , min ( $G , $B ) ) ;
```

So ; is it safe to assume if the following function returns the same `$min` value ?

```php
$min = min ( $R , $G , $B ) ;
```

Comment: No, their results should be identical. The first should be more efficient, though.

Comment: just min(2, 1, -2) == min(min(2,1), -2) ,These all are equal , leads to same results, also in min() You can compare unlimited number of values. (as per Documentation)

Comment: @raina77ow: You are totally right, they _should_ be identical. The truth is they are not: `min('0', 0, '.') !== min('0', min(0, '.'))` (as [PleaseStand suggests in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16878508/548696)). Proof: http://ideone.com/PZeSQI

Comment: The reason you may see `min(a,min(b,c))` is that in many libraries, the `min()` function can only accept two parameters. In PHP, they are identical, minus any odd edge cases regarding comparing mixed data types.

Comment: @Matthew [link](http://clarion.pesow.com/ENG/ALGORITHMS/algorithms_colors.htm) These are colour algorithms for an open source .NET extension. I have seen many ones written with just 2 parameters in various languages but there are many of them as well, written in PHP. I think there are a lot of similar **bad-formed** PHP functions around ported carelessly from any other language or from one another. Thanks for pointing this limitation out.

Comment: @Tadeck You're right, of course; I've thought about it, but totally forgot about `'0'`/`0` mix. And it's not even about mixed datatypes - it's about the rule that _order_ of operands influences the result of `min`. That, in turn, obviously gives such wonderful result when `'0'` and `0` are mixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* a difference, although it is unlikely to be encountered in practice.

```
php> $a = '0'; $b = 0; $c = '.';
php> var_dump(min($b,$c));
int(0)
php> var_dump(min($a,min($b,$c)));
string(1) "0"
php> var_dump(min($a,$b,$c));
string(1) "."
```

Relevant quote from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php):

> PHP will evaluate a non-numeric string as 0 if compared to integer, but still return the string if it's seen as the numerically lowest value. If multiple arguments evaluate to 0, min() will return the lowest alphanumerical string value if any strings are given, else a numeric 0 is returned.

Comment: I do not want to start flame war, but this is one of many inconsistencies in PHP that PHP developer needs to take into account. `min($a, $b, $c) !== min($a, min($b, $c))` is a very good example for that. Upvote goes to you.

Comment: So the result is dependent upon variables I think. It is nice to know that these two functions will not produce the same result **whatever** the case.

Comment: The true WTH of PHP is that `min($a, $b)` !== `min($b, $a)` in too many cases.